# How can you register an Android Loader without starting it?

Tags: android, loader

I'm trying to implement a custom loader to handle some data loading when the user clicks a button

on my click handler I have this code:

```
LoaderManager.InitLoader(LOAD_DATA_ID, null, this).forceLoad();
```

which does work correctly

my problem is that if I register

```
LoaderManager.InitLoader(LOAD_DATA_ID, null, this);
```

in the OnCreate method, the loader starts automatically, which I do not want.

if I don't register it, I stop receiving results.

I tried only registering it when `savedInstanceState != null` , but then if there is a configuration change the loader still fires.

is there something I can do to avoid the above problem?

EDIT: this is the solution I have found so far, it seems to work

First of all I created a `public Loader loader` variable in my data Fragment (it is a fragment that has its retain instance state set to true so it will survive configuration changes) and I updated my code as follows:

in OnCreate()

```
if (_data.loader != null) {
    LoaderManager.InitLoader(LOAD_DATA_ID, null, this);
    _data.loader.progress_handler = new Handler(this); //this is a handler I use to get progress updates
}
```

in onCreateLoader:

```
_data.loader = new MyProgressTaskLoader(this);
_data.loader.progress_handler = new Handler(this);
_data.loader;
```

in onLoadFinished

```
_data.loader = null;
// process results
```

and in the click method:

```
LoaderManager.InitLoader(LOAD_DATA_ID, null, this).forceLoad();
```

the above seems to work, but if there is a better way I would love to hear it

Comment: you simply call `InitLoader` in your `OnClickListener` and wait for a data in `LoaderCallbacks#onLoadFinished` , thats all

Comment: yeah but when a configuration change occurs the new activity created does not receive updates if you don't call InitLoader in OnCreate with this method